# looping through a cellfun calculation

Tags: matlab

Hi I have the following:

```
for j = 1:N
    for i = 1:N
        vecdir(i,:) = pos(i,:) - pos(j,:);
        dist(i,:) = pdist2(pos(i,:),pos(j,:));
        norm(i,:) = vecdir(i,:)./(dist(i,:)).^2;
    end
    r{j} = norm;

end

u = {or};
```

where I have two object u and r:

```
>> u

u = 

    [9x3 double]

>> r

r = 

  Columns 1 through 8

    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]

  Column 9

    [9x3 double]
```

and I want to take each cell of r, and take the cross product of each element in that cell, with each element in the cell u and sum the result into one vector size [1 3]. so far I can do this one cell (of r) at a time using:

```
b_func = @(u)nansum(cell2mat(cellfun(@(v)cross(u,v)', {r{1}}, 'Un', 0))', 1);
b = cellfun(b_func, u, 'UniformOutput', 0)
```

where

```
b = [1x3 double]
```

however what I want to do is do this for **all** cells in r so that I end up with an object:

```
b = 

  Columns 1 through 8

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]

  Column 9

    [1x3 double]
```

where each cell is the calculation mentioned above, but has iterated through each cell of r. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
b= cellfun(@(x) nansum(cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Test:

```
>> u = {randi(5,[9 3])}
u = 
    [9x3 double]
>> r = arrayfun(@(x) randi(5,[9 3]),1:8,'UniformOutput',false)
r = 
  Columns 1 through 6
    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]
  Columns 7 through 8
    [9x3 double]    [9x3 double]
>> b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(cross(u{1},x)),r,'UniformOutput',false)
b  = 
  Columns 1 through 6
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
  Columns 7 through 8
    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can reshape it, such that the cells go along the third dimension, convert it to an array and sum:

```
b = nansum(cell2mat(reshape(cellfun(@(v)cross(u,v), r, 'Un', 0),1,1,[])),1);
```

Then go back to cells and fix dimensions:

```
bfinal = shiftdim(mat2cell(b,[1],[3],ones(1,size(b,3))),1);
```

Result:

```
>> bfinal

bfinal = 

  Columns 1 through 6

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]

  Columns 7 through 9

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
```

Comment: @Phillip F - thanks for your reply Phillip, I get the following error when using your answer ??? Error using ==> cross at 31
A and B must be same size.

Error in ==> @(v)cross(u,v)

I suspect this is to with how you declare r as r is not the same size as u.